# Why my Android App doesn't have ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I have some stupid question and problem here.
I have develop an android app and its  60% done right now, but i have just noticed that my MainActivity doesn't have any action bar, but another activity have it.
Please master, can you tell me what happen? i want to use actionBar/toolBar on my MainActivity too.
I have try to edit my style.xml file, but its still like that..
NB. this is my MainActivity.java code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
private static Button BtnINewTrans;
private static Button BtnIViewCash;
private static Button BtnIAddCateg;
Spinner my_Spinner;
DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
public static String catSelected = null;

//ArrayAdapter<String> adapterCategory;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    my_Spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnCategSelect);
    my_Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    select_spinner_Category();
    onButtonClickButtonListener();



}

/*ArrayList<String> my_array = new ArrayList<String>();
my_array = getTableValues();*/


/*ArrayAdapter my_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_row, my_array);
My_spinner.setAdapter(my_Adapter);*/

public void select_spinner_Category () {
    my_Spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnCategSelect);
    DatabaseHelper dbH = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

    List<String> listCategory = dbH.getAllCategory();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterCategory = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listCategory);

    adapterCategory
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    my_Spinner.setAdapter(adapterCategory);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                           long id){
    String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected "+label,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    catSelected = label;
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

public String getCatSelected(){
    return catSelected;
}

    /*ArrayList<String> arrayCategory;
    arrayCategory = dbHelper.getAllCategory();
    selectCategory = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnCategSelect);
    ArrayAdapter adapterCategory  = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayCategory);
   // adapterCategory = new ArrayList<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.id.spnCategSelect, AllCategoryList);
    adapterCategory.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    selectCategory.setAdapter(adapterCategory);
    selectCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

}*/


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    return true;
}


public void onButtonClickButtonListener(){
    BtnINewTrans = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNewTrans);
    BtnINewTrans.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intentNewTrans = new Intent ("com.example.ever_ncn.cashflow.NewTransaction");
                    startActivity(intentNewTrans);
                }
            }
    );

    BtnIViewCash = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnViewCashflow);
    BtnIViewCash.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intentViewCash = new Intent ("com.example.ever_ncn.cashflow.ViewCashflow");
                    startActivity(intentViewCash);
                }
            }
    );

    BtnIAddCateg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddCateg);
    BtnIAddCateg.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intentAddCateg = new Intent ("com.example.ever_ncn.cashflow.CategorySetting");
                    startActivity(intentAddCateg);
                }
            }
    );

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

and this my MainActivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/Title"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="#f325272f"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/NewTransaction"
    android:id="@+id/btnNewTrans"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="69dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ViewCashflow"
    android:id="@+id/btnViewCashflow"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnNewTrans"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/AddCategory"
    android:id="@+id/btnAddCateg"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="94dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnNewTrans" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/RateUs"
    android:id="@+id/btnRate"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnAddCateg"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnAddCateg"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnAddCateg" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Setting"
    android:id="@+id/btnSetting"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnRate"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnRate"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnRate" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/About"
    android:id="@+id/btnAbout"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnSetting"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnSetting"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnSetting" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/Trademark"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textColor="#f325272f"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spnCategSelect"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnAddCateg"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnViewCashflow"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnViewCashflow"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="@string/SelectCategory"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_above="@+id/spnCategSelect"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

this one for my Style.xml file

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="list">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>

    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_below">@+id/textView16</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_above">@+id/textView17</item>
</style>
```

Here is for my new question on comment, colors.xml source

```
<resources>
    <color name ="primaryColor">#9C27B0</color> //purple
    <color name="primaryColorDark">#7B1FA2</color>
    <color name="accentColor">#FF5722</color>

</resources>
```

Thanks Before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html#ApiLevel7) your `Activity` must extend `AppCompatActivity`.

(The docs say `ActionBarActivity`, but it has since been deprecated in favor of `AppCompatActivity` - see [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html).)

Comment: but, on my MainActivity i must implement OnItemSelectedListener, with using ActionBarActivity i cant implement OnItemSelectedListener,, how to solve this ?

Comment: yes, you can. like so:

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener { ... }

Comment: ooh yea its can, i don't know last minute before i ask this question i try to do that and got some error, but now its work..
one more thing sir, i want to costumize my actionbar using colors.xml file, which i have created before, but why its not work?? i'll update my colors.xml on my question...

Comment: ActionBarActivity is deprecated. You need to use AppCompatActivity now.

Comment: Varundroid is right - updated my answer. Does your ActionBar color work now?

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend `AppCompatActivity` instead of Activity.

**NOTE**

`ActionBarActivity` is **deprecated** so please don't use it and use `AppCompatActivity` instead. Using deprecated class is not recommended as It can be removed or stopped working any time and also deprecated means developer will not support it any more and you might miss on future updates.